# Should I be able to use an ObservableCollection[PSObject] as the ItemsSource of a DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, powershell, observablecollection, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to create a UI in PowerShell which has a `DataGrid` which updates as the source updates, so I'm using an `ObservableCollection<PSObject>`.  But when I set it as the `ItemsSource`, `DataGrid` doesn't generate any columns.  If I use the original array, it does.  Here's an example:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type -AssemblyName WindowsBase

[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="500"
        Width="600">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
              x:Name="dataGrid" 
              IsReadOnly="True"
              Margin="6" />
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
              x:Name="observableDataGrid" 
              IsReadOnly="True"
              Margin="6" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
"@

$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

$dataGrid = $window.FindName("dataGrid")
$observableDataGrid = $window.FindName("observableDataGrid")

$results = Get-Process | Select-Object -Property ProcessName,Id,Handles,NPM,PM,VM,WS

$results2 = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[PSObject] -ArgumentList @(,$results)

$dataGrid.ItemsSource = $results
$observableDataGrid.ItemsSource = $results2

$Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Comment: try setting auto generating columns to true for datagrid and see if that helps. also ensure that the collection has elements and they have properties, fields may not work.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to replace the `ObservableCollection<PSObject>` with an `ObservableCollection<Object>`.

Comment: Please don't ask questions in answers. Answers are reserved for answering questions.

Comment: I've removed the statement.

Comment: Thank you. If you still want to know why, then please ask that in your question instead.

Comment: I don't but I can't mark the question answered, yet.

Comment: A little bit shorter: `$results2 = [System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[PSObject]]$results`